# Drawing ROBDD diagram

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I'm trying to draw ROBDD diagram.

```
\begin{forest}
  BDT
  [$A$
  [$D$
  [$\top$]
]
[$B \vee D$
[$\bot$]
]
 [$C$]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

This is my output:

[image]

However I would like to connect some of ROBDD elements like here:

[image]

I'm using forest package. Could you please help me to fix this?

Comment: Welcome. Are you fixed on the `forest` package? Technically, your diagram isn't a tree anymore. These diagrams mighe be easier to draw with `tikz-cd` or other TikZ tools. That said, you can just add `\path[->] (!11) edge (!21) (!3)  edge (!21) edge (!2) (!1)  edge (!2);` before `\end{forest}`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm not fixed on forest package. Could you please post answer that draws correct ROBDD?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel thank you very much... I will accept answer if you add it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end of the tree (before `\end{forest}`) you can arbitrary TikZ code which gets applied on the level of the root. You can use forest's relative nodewalk with the `!` prefix. Here `(!21)` specifies the 1st child of the 2nd child (of the root node).

Using `\forestoption{edge}` allows us to use the same edge specification as is valid for root node.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest} for tree = {edge = ->}
%  BDT
[$A$
  [$D$
    [$\top$]
  ]
  [$B \vee D$
    [$\bot$]
  ]
  [$C$]
]
\path[every edge/.append style/.expanded=\forestoption{edge}]
  (!11) edge (!21)
  (!3)  edge (!21) edge (!2)
  (!1)  edge (!2);
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thank you very much, could you use circles for diagram elements?

Answer (score 1):

Is possible to realize your diagram using also `tikz-cd` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  & A \arrow[ld] \arrow[d] \arrow[rd] &  \\
D \arrow[d] \arrow[r]&  B \vee D \arrow[d]  & \arrow[l] C \arrow[ld] \\
\top           & \bot                              &             
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```